# My output keeps getting appended to the previous output

Tags: c++, io

I'm writing a program to convert infix to postfix.  I read infix data from text file then convert it.

The problem is when outputing the results, it takes the previous one and adds it to next one until end. I've been trying to fix this but I can't figure out what is happening!  Can anyone see the problem?

**Input:**

```
    4
    5+7
    7*5
```

**Output:**

```
    4
    457+
    457+75*
```

Then prints again like this:

```
 4457+457+75*
```

**My code:**

```
int main()
{
    stack<char> Stack;
    string postFix = "";
    const int SIZE = 100;
    char input[SIZE];

    ifstream file("tests.txt");
    file >> input;

    do
    {
       // code

        cout<<"PostFix is :  " << postFix <<"\n";

        file >> input ;
    } while( file && file.peek() != EOF);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried running this in a debugger?

Comment: Look for \n in your loop.  Everytime you do, output and clear the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm - postFix.clear() at the end of the loop?

Also, try converting the loop to this:

```
ifstream file("tests.txt");
while(file.good()) {
    file >> input;
    ...
    cout << "PostFix is : " << postFix << endl;
    postFix.clear();
}
```

Comment: I just missed to clear the stack. i tried while( file && file.peek() != EOF) and now i good.. thank you !!